# Is Textwatcher is used only for Edittext android

Tags: android

I want to use `TextWatcher`(textChangelistener) for a `TextView` in android I made a study on that there I came to know that, it is possible to have `OnTextChangeListener` for `EditText` only. But my `TextView` will automatically change according to the changes in the someother `EditText`s. so I want to have a `OnTextChangedListener` to proceed with further calculations..

can anyone help me doing this!!!!!  Thanks in Advance

Comment: yes you can use textwatcher for your textview as well in the same way they has been used for edittext

Comment: What exactly are you asking? I think your question is unclear, you should edit and rephrase it.

Comment: `addTextChangedListener()` is a method of `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question `EditText's` text is changed by user dynamically so we need `TextWatcher` for `EditText`, but in case of `TextView` whatever text is being changed will be changed by developer only. So you should perform operations on it whenever you are setting text to `TextView`. Still if you want to use that use it as follows.

```
textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    boolean editing=false;

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (!editing){
           editing=true;
           s.append("A");
           editing=false;
    }


    }
});
```